# How to configure Wordpress in its own directory using nginx and php?

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I have a VPS I'm trying to configure to run a Wordpress site.
I also want to run a NodeJS app on it.

Here's what I'd like to do:

The NodeJS location:
/var/www/domain/public_html/webapp
Initially I just want to serve an HTML page (index.html) via nginx as my webapp isn't ready.

The Wordpress location:
/var/www/domain/public_html/blog

This would be it. No other directories.
Wordpress is served from the /blog URL and the webapp would be served from root (/).
I don't want to put /blog under the webroot, I'd like them to be separate.

... excerpt from my nginx.conf:

```
  index index.html index.htm index.php;

  location /blog {
    root /var/www/domain/public_html/blog;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      include php.conf; // no issues when Wordpress is root
    }
  }

  location / {
    root /var/www/domain/public_html/webapp;

    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
```

I've literally spent more time on this than I'm comfortable admitting w/o success.

Can anyone help me w/this?

It would be much appreciated!

Comment: One difference I can see with my working setup that does this is "try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;"  . You can look at my working config here https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-pt1-introduction-configuration-downloads/

Comment: What is the problem you are having?